# use joint bibtex library in multiple files

Tags: bibtex, lyx, include

My document is split into several smaller ones which are included in a joint document. Now how can I use one bibtex file for all subdocuments?

I am using lyx, but all plain tex solutions are also welcome.

Comment: To make sure I understand, in your child document you do not want to include the bibtex inset, but you do want to use the references from it which is in the master? If so, does the following help?: In your child document go to Document > Settings, check the box "Select default master document", and then browse to select the master lyx file, and then click "OK".

Comment: Thanks for the awesome hint I wasn't aware of! Could you make it an answer along with the link https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Multidoc#multipart-bib ?

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your child document to use information from a different .lyx file, LyX needs to know where to look.

In your child document go to Document > Settings, check the box "Select default master document", and then browse to select the master lyx file, and then click "OK".

Some useful information can also be bound on [this](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Multidoc#multipart-bib) LyX wiki page.